# Vim syntax match changes based on function type name keyword

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-c

I've written a C code syntax rule to highlight function names in function definitions as such:

[image]

This is the syntax rule written in ~/.vim/syntax/c.vim:

```
syntax match cCustomFunc /\w\+\s\+\zs\w\+(/he=e-1
highlight default link cCustomFunc Function
```

However, when the type in the function definition is a C keyword, the syntax highlighting fails. For example:

[image]

Any keyword type such as char, int, void, etc. causes it to fail.

I've tried putting "contains=Type" at the end of the syntax match rule, but it did not work.

How can I make my syntax highlighting rule work when the type in the function definition is a keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the keyword is preventing your regex from matching, since the regex you're using needs to match the whole line, even though you're using `\zs` to start the capture only at the function name, after the keyword...

You can solve that by using a look-behind regex with [`\@<=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D), rather than `\zs`.

This seems to work ok:

```
syntax match cCustomFunc /\(\w\+\s\+\)\@<=\w\+(/he=e-1
```

Comment: That works. Thanks.